# Haskell: generate HaTeX output from IO [[String]]

Tags: haskell, monads

I am trying to write a Haskell program that generates Latex code out of a text-based input file. I want to use [HaTeX](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaTeX) for this purpose.

As a first step, I want to generate links to IMDB for movies stored in a text-file. The format is one movie per line, with Title and IMDB URL separated by the | character:

```
Movie 1 | http://url1
Movie 2 | http://url2
```

The code I have so far is the following:

```
import System.IO
import Data.Char(toUpper)
import Data.List.Split(splitOn)

import Text.LaTeX.Packages.Hyperref
import Text.LaTeX

main :: IO()
main = execLaTeXT generateFromFile  >>= renderFile "output.txt"

generateFromFile :: Monad m => LaTeXT_ m
generateFromFile = do
  m <- getMovies -- AFAIK this should "bind" the IO Monad, i.e. m should be [[String]]
  (generateFromStrLists m)

-- Takes a list of lists of strings and generates links
generateFromStrLists :: Monad m => [[String]] -> LaTeXT_ m
generateFromStrLists [] = fromString ""
generateFromStrLists (y:x) = do
  (generate u t)
  (generateFromStrLists x)
  where
    u = y !! 0
    t = y !! 1

-- Generate the movie link for a given title and URL
generate :: Monad m => String -> String -> LaTeXT_ m
generate u t = (href [] (createURL u) (fromString t))

getMovies :: IO [[String]]
getMovies = do
  lines <- getLines "movies.lst" -- [String]
  return $ map (splitOn "|") lines

getLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getLines filename = do
  text <- readFile filename
  return $ lines text
```

If I manually call generateFromStrLists with a hand-crafted [[String]], the output is generated properly.

I guess the problem I am seeing is related to Monads (but I am not sure). I guess that I 1) either don't understand the IO Monad sufficiently, or 2) there is a mix-up of using the IO Monad and the Monad for generating the Latex code properly (probably in generateFromStrLists).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `lift` the `IO` action to a `LaTeXT_ IO` action:

```
generateFromFile :: LaTeXT_ IO
generateFromFile = do
    m <- liftIO getMovies
    generateFromStrLists m
```

You also have to remove the `Monad m` constraint from the type signature and specify that it's working on the `IO` Monad.

---

The short explanation is that `LaTeXT_` is a Monad transformer, it essentially can add the `LaTeX` monad's behavior to any other `Monad`.  You specifically want to perform `IO` inside the `LaTeXT_ m` Monad, so `m` has to be `IO` (or more generally `MonadIO m => LaTeXT_ m` would work).  What this gives you is the ability to "stack" multiple types of transformers on top of each other, usually with `IO` at the bottom of this stack (there is no `IO` transformer, it's too primitive), so that you can have various different behaviors for a complex application.

So what `liftIO` does is "lift" an operation from an `IO` like monad (in this case specifically the `IO` monad) into the transformer monad that you're using.  For transformers in general, there is the `lift` operation, but since performing `IO` is a pretty common action, there is a specialized `liftIO` action that has the signature

```
liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a
```

In the context of the `LaTeXT IO` monad, it's type would get specialized to

```
liftIO :: IO a -> LaTeXT IO a
```

so `liftIO getMovies` would have the type `LaTeXT IO [[String]]`.  Inside a particular monadic computation, all the expressions have to have to belong to the same monad, otherwise something like the following would be possible:

```
import Data.Map as M

getValues :: String -> String -> Map String Int -> Maybe (Int, Int)
getValues s1 s2 m = do
    v1 <- M.lookup s1 m
    v2 <- M.lookup s2 m
    print (v1, v2)
    return (v1, v2)
```

Since `M.lookup` is a `Maybe` monad action, and `print` is an `IO` monad action, they are not compatible.  This is essentially the problem you were experiencing.

Comment: Just a little comment. `LaTeXT_ m` is just a type synonym for `LaTeXT m ()`, which itself is _not_ a monad transformer. It is just a way to specify at the type level that the computation does not return anything. `LaTeXT` is the monad transformer, because applied to a monad `m` it gives you another monad, namely `LaTeXT m` (like in the case of `IO` you mention). That being said, good answer. :)